# Automation Bot using Visual Studio

Tags: pdf, web, download, automation, bots

I'm a novice to programming and bot creation. I wanted to know what is the best language to use for creating a bot that downloads a list of pdf files from a website. I'm new to this so I'm not sure where to begin. I've looked on youtube and other sites for similar bots/programs but haven't been able to find one. Any guidance is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: a simple search of :how to download pdfs from website with [insert language] will give enough results. Better is to pick a language and start learning the basics. Id suggest python

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. And please...no screeenshots.  As it stands, this question is off-topic.